# is there a way to grab variable in body tag and use it in head tags

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, head

I am trying to supply the title tag for facebook open graph with custom content for the send button. As you know the meta for the open graph is in the head tags and the information is in a variable in the body, therefore I need to use the variable before it's declared. Hints the problem.

I have searched around and tried a few of my own ideas and had no luck. 
Is there a way either with php, jquery or ajax to grab the variable and use it in the head tags?

Thanks guys.

Comment: declare variable at the very top

Comment: The variable is created according to conditions in a loop and from an included page. So this would mean I would have to run the loop twice. Once before the head tags and once in the body tags. Somehow I think there is a better way.  I will keep this in mind though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it..

I would write a controller file and put the head content and body content into arrays, then I would search for naming conventions or functions in the body.. then add the function or variable to the head array.

Finally, build the template.
arrays:

```
$head = array();
$body = array();

$head[] = '<title>My Title</title>';
$head[] = '<script>some script here</script>';
$body[] = '<h3>Hello World</h3>';
$body[] = myfunction();
```

Now you can search the $body array with a pregmatch looking for myfunction or if you prefix the variables with $head_myvariable you can search for head with pregmatch.. if it exists.. Simply add the variable to your head array:

```
$head[] = $mybodyvariable;
```

Now you can publish everything:

```
foreach($head as $h) {
     echo $h;
}
foreach($body as $b) {
     echo $b;
}
```

You will need to do a little research on preg_match as the regex is different for everytype of search.. so google this 
php: preg_match

Good luck, hope that helps.

Comment: Better yet.  rather than a preg_match, I would write a function like Joomla and Drupal does: addToHead($myvariable);

Comment: ... then in that function simply add the value of the variable to the head array: $head[] = $myvariable;